# How to check if a user is idle on a website using php

Tags: php

How can I check if a user is idle for 10 minutes or more using php?

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720293/checking-user-status-active-idle-on-a-web-page)

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140505)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time the users does something, update a timestamp for that user in a database. To find idle users, query everyone whose timestamp is older than 10 minutes.

Comment: this will be heavy. for every request you are asking him to make a database trip creating unnecessary overheads. you can minimize it by making use of cookies or session variable

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar one excess query won't make 'unnecessary overheads', believe me. If it's an overload project (which I'm sure is not) you always can save sessions with timestamp in memcached or something. But in this case it rationally just save last login date in database.

Comment: how can i check Each time the users does something?

Comment: Kichu, it's up to you to solve. You may write a function you call on each page load.

Answer (score 0):

make use of session variable, store timestamp in it. for every request update the timestamp.

Comment: How will another process tell which users that are idle?